# What's the purpose of Angular routes with same path to different components?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've come across some Angular code in a prominent project that I find rather confusing.

The code in question comes from [Amazon Web Services' Cognito quickstart project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular-quickstart/blob/master/src/app/app.routes.ts). This file I reference, `app.routes.ts` contains the app's routes. Peculiarly however, the two root routes have the same path but specify different destination.

Theses are **both** root routes:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/securehome',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

How can there be two routes with the same path but leading to different places? If this doesn't cause an error, it should at least be totally useless shouldn't it? Is there something I am missing here (since this code was written by someone who seems to know what he is doing) ?

---

Here is the full code:

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
            {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
            {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
            {path: 'confirmRegistration/:username', component: RegistrationConfirmationComponent},
            {path: 'resendCode', component: ResendCodeComponent},
            {path: 'forgotPassword/:email', component: ForgotPassword2Component},
            {path: 'forgotPassword', component: ForgotPasswordStep1Component},
            {path: 'newPassword', component: NewPasswordComponent},
            {path: '', component: HomeLandingComponent}
        ]
    },
];

const secureHomeRoutes: Routes = [
    {

        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/securehome',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'securehome', component: SecureHomeComponent, children: [
        {path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent},
        {path: 'jwttokens', component: JwtComponent},
        {path: 'myprofile', component: MyProfileComponent},
        {path: 'useractivity', component: UseractivityComponent},
        {path: '', component: MyProfileComponent}]
    }
];

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            ...homeRoutes,
            ...secureHomeRoutes,
            {
                path: '',
                component: HomeComponent
            }
        ]
    },


];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: I think you are right, this one looks badly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I can see only see one use case of the following .

> He wants to use guards for the his routes , this is the reason the
>   routes are names secured and home routes but i donot see any guards
>   being configured for the the children , this is what i think he might
>   be doing or has skipped .

This is the best reason i can conjure up :)